# Jquery dynamic form does not work

Tags: jquery, html

I have try to create Jquery dynamic from using http://jsfiddle.net/pixelentity/aABLD/24/  and I have created my html file. but It does not work that means it show html page but does not show dynamic form when click the add button. this is my code

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
 jQuery(function($) {

 var multiTags = $("#multi");

function handler(e) {
    var jqEl = $(e.currentTarget);
    var tag = jqEl.parent();
    switch (jqEl.attr("data-action")) {
    case "add":
        tag.after(tag.clone().find("input").val("").end());
        break;
    case "delete":
        tag.remove();
        break;
    }
    return false;
 }

function save(e) {
    var tags = multiTags.find("input.tag").map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get().join(',');
    alert(tags);
    return false;
}

multiTags.submit(save).find("a").live("click", handler);
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">

form {
font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
}

form div{
margin-bottom:10px;
}

form a {
font-size: 12px;
padding: 4px 10px;
border: 1px solid #444444;
background: #555555;
color:#f7f7f7;
text-decoration:none;
vertical-align: middle;
 }

 form a:hover{
   color:#ffffff;
   background:#111111;   
 }

 #multi label {
  margin-left:20px;
  margin-right:5px;
  font-size:12px;
  background:#f7f7f7;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  border:1px solid #cccccc;
  vertical-align: middle;
  }

  #multi input[type="text"]{
  height:22px;
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px; 
  border:1px solid #cccccc;
  vertical-align: middle;
  }

  #multi input[type="submit"]{
   margin-left:20px;
   border:none;
   background:#222222;
   outline:none;
   color:#ffffff;
   padding: 4px 10px;
   font-size:12px;
   }


    </style>

   </head>



   <body>


   <form id="multi">
    <div>
    <label>Tag</label><input class="tag" type="text" name="" type="text" />
    <a href="#" data-action="add">add</a>
    <a href="#" data-action="delete">delete</a>
   </div>
    <input type="submit" value="save" >
 </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

`
  what is the wrong with my code? can some one please help to solve this?

Comment: You have to be more specific, what is the expected result?

Comment: when Click the add button it should add new record that means it duplicate. please see my above url and do demo then you will get more clear idea

Comment: I try your code in fiddle and it works fine,where is your problem?

Comment: I open my html code with firefox browser and Crome and then click the "Add" button it does not add the new field as the demo. that is the my problem. have you tried my code in your PC?

Comment: Questions that say "doesn't work" bug me. Please take time to craft a more meaningful title. Who up voted this question?

Comment: Is there any jquery plugging do I have to use? I only run this html file local.

Comment: Hey dude,i try it on my FireFox 20.0.1 and Chrome 26.0.1410.64 m both of them works fine.I look over your code again and I thought maybe because your jQuery version is too old,try higher level.

Comment: @ jarvanJiang: what is the version that you use ? can you please copy your src in <script> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your jQuery version to higer version but don't use 1.9.1 or higher because the 'live' method has been removed.Or you can change the 'live' method to 'on' method with using jQuery 1.9.1 or higher.